# Dropdown menu, z-index problems

Tags: html, css, z-index, layer

I've got a problem. I have a drop down menu, but the drop down list is always one layer behind the body although the z-index of menu is set to 999 and z index of body set to -999

Please chceck http://www.w3dominik.com/x/finemoney/ (the menu on top right, it says dropdown and should have 2 options, only 1 is now visible)

Thanks for help

Comment: Your site is prone to change. Please update this question to include the code and a fiddle.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This will fix it for you:

```
#header_wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

You often need to set the z-index on the outermost parent (particularly in older versions of IE).

Comment: "You often need to set the z-index on the outermost parent" this is what helped me find the offending z-index, thank you!

Comment: Old post, but something I missed again. I was changing the child element and never thought to set the parent. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just add `position: relative`, z-index won't work without position.

```
header ul {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}
```